# Applying changes for Vue application executed by GO

Tags: node.js, go, vue.js, webpack

I used Go to create a very simple web app with only one web page. In this project I used Vue CLI to install webpack. If I run vue application by npm, all is fine and works perfectly, but I want to get the ability to work with vue when I run go web app. For this I built vue-project by npm `npm run build` and get dist directory, after that in go application I wrote something like this:

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web-vue/dist")))

    http.HandleFunc("/", HomePage)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HomePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("web-vue/dist/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w,"SerGorn")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("template executing error: ", err)
    }
}
```

It works fine with one exception, when I change .vue file, for applying this changes, needs rebuild app by npm again. How I could solve this problem? Any Idea?  Or may be it's wrong way and better if work with vue will be in only node.js?

Comment: I'm not sure how Vue does it, but in other JS frameworks, `build` commands are only executed *only* before you deploy to production. When developing locally you don't really need minification etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue with any backend. Seems like FileServer or your browser caches your static files. You could use `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to avoid caching.

Answer (score 0):

The .vue source files must be processed in order to be served as HTML by a web server. You cannot modify .vue files and expect to see the changes in a web browser running against a production web server. As such, after modifications you must run `npm run build` which will process the .vue files and generate valid HTML files into `/dist`.

Now reviewing your code, I see that you could further simplify it by doing this:

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web-vue/dist/")))
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web-vue/dist/")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```